# How to load Image on Android from URI using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to load a Image from URI on a Cordova project.

This code below works fine on Windows Phone, but on Android I can't load image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnTest").on("click", loadImage);
    $("#btnTestUsingDataUrl").on("click", loadImageFromDataURL);
});

function loadImage(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: 0 });
}

function loadImageFromDataURL() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccessUsingDataURL, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: 0 });
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) { 
    var imgProfile = document.getElementById('imgTest');
    imgProfile.src = imageURI;
    alert(imageURI);
}

function onPhotoDataSuccessUsingDataURL(imageURI) { 
    var imgProfile = document.getElementById('imgTest');
    imgProfile.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

The URI returned on Android is  **"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A3449"**;

Android version: 5.0.2.

Cordova version: 5.1.1.

Camera Plugin: org.apache.cordova.camera.

**The example using DataUrl works fine on both Android and Windows Phone.**

Can someone help me?

Comment: remove the camera plugin and install the latest from npm with cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: @jcesarmobile I created a new project and added the new version of plugin.

Comment: and the problem persists?

Comment: I've changed my code and worked. I'm getting a URI and then load the file to base64 and updated my Image. I'll post the code at night. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I'm using the **Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI** to get the path of the Image and store it to get the image later.

After that, I'm using the **FileReader** to get the Image on Base64 format and then append on a **img tag**.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnTest").on("click", loadImage);
});

function loadImage() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: 0 });
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError);
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function resOnError(error) {
    alert("resOnError - " + error.code);
}

function resolveOnSuccess(entry) {
    entry.file(function (fileInput) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
            var base64 = evt.target.result;
            var imgBase64 = $('#imgTest');
            imgBase64.attr('src', base64);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput);
    }, function () { alert('fail on trying to read the file.') });
}
```

I hope it helps someone. =)